# Regex to match dashes(-) within apostrophe(')

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I'm trying to write a regular expression to match match dashes(-) only within apostrophe(')

Example Data:

```
( NOT TABLE-FIELD BEWEEN 'XX-XX'  AND 'XX-XX'  ) AND ( TABLE-FIELD = 'XXX-XXX-XXX' )
```

Expectation on match - between '' and it should ignore -  outside '' example ,  TABLE-FIELD

( NOT TABLE-FIELD BEWEEN 'XX`-`XX'  AND 'XX`-`XX'  ) AND ( TABLE-FIELD = 'XX`-`XX`-`XX' )

Came up with this `(')()[^ ]*` up to now it will match what's inside ' but not sure what expression to write to limit it down only to -

Result,

( NOT TABLE-FIELD BEWEEN `'XX-XX'`  AND `'XX-XX'`  ) AND ( TABLE-FIELD = `'XX-XX-XX'` )

Comment: What language/tool/platform/framework/flavor are you using? What's the ultimate purpose?

Comment: POSIX standard 1003.2

Comment: The POSIX version might tell part of what @InSync asked, but only if we look up the details. So: *"What language/tool/platform/framework/flavor are you using? What's the ultimate purpose?"*

Comment: following will not work with BRE abd ERE but PCRE because needs lookahead to check the number of single quotes is even : `[^']*(?=(('[^']*){2})*$)(*SKIP)(?!)|-` reversing the condition discards the text outside the single quotes

Comment: @AdrianHHH  , why exactly the language/tool/platform/framework matter here ? , isnt regex should be something generic within the standard ?

Comment: Just quoting a POSIX number tells me nothing, unless I go to the effort of looking up the standard. Even then, it is possible that Perl, Awk, Sed, Vi, Emacs and so on use different RegEx versions. It seems to me that you are asking us to do your research for you.

Comment: If there never occurs a space inside the quotes, another idea can be: [`-(?=\S*')`](https://regex101.com/r/2D8b1G/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it can be assumed that there are always an even number of single quotes we can infer that a hyphen is within a single-quote-delimited phrase if and only if the number of single quotes following the hyphen in the string is odd. That happens if the following regular expression is matched.

```
-(?=[^']*'(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4owR5n/1)

Comment: Thank you @cary-swoveland this works fine ,